# Can shapes be made to continue across grid planes in Illustrator's perspective tool?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, perspective

I made a logo sketch that I decided to make inside the Illustrator perspective tool.  This logo has shapes that wrap around a 3d rectangular shape.  I looked around on the web and found some information and tutorials on revolving shapes and mapping symbols to them but nothing covering what am trying to accomplish.

Below: Is there a way to make the red rectangle continue from the edge of the right grid plane onto the left blue grid plane instead of matching two shapes together like the two green rectangles.

In this example everything is square or rectangular but with the introduction of a curved shape matching the perspective pretty hard. If there is a solution could you also apply it to curved shapes in the same fashion?

Thank you!

Mac OSX 10.10 and
Adobe Illustrator CS6

[image: perspective grid reference image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware an object can only be associated with one plane. A workaround is to split the object in to two halves and attach each to the correct plane.

**A Workaround & Example**

Created a clipping mask over half the object you want to wrap around two planes - up to where the object will wrap around to the next plane. Duplicate the object and edit the clipping make so the opposite half is visible through the mask.

[image]

Use the **Perspective Selection Tool** (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>) To attach the object to the correct plane and place it where you want.

Make the opposite plane active using the active plane widget, then repeat the process of attaching and placing on the perspective grid for the other half of the object.

[image]

You can move the objects vertically along the perspective grid as you need with no problem.

[image]

If you need to move the object along the horizontal axis (i.e. change where the object wraps around the planes of perspective grid) you will need to alter the clipping mask. This is difficult while the objects are still on the perspective grid so you may want to repeat the process of clipping the halves and re-attaching the objects to the perspective grid - or roughly edit the masks until the position is finalised, then repeat the process.

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure i wouldn't call that a workaround.

Comment: Haha yeh fair point @joojaa. It's a workaround to the fact that it doesn't work automatically I guess.

Comment: Yes but by that logic using illustrator is a workaround since the logo does not materialize auto-magically.

Comment: Very true. And I'm sure some people do think like that!

Comment: Personally I think people like that dont have vision. They clearly want to skip the **do XXX** for me apps and go directly to **Give me money and Influence** instead.

Comment: I agree. Life (like design and everything else) is about process. If *all* you care about is outcome you are too narrow minded.