# Is it possible to add perspective effects to type objects in Illustrator CC?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, perspective

I'd like to apply a perspective effect to some type in Illustrator (CC 2015 OSX) but the perspective options are greyed out. I tried to create outlines and rasterise but that didn't resolve the issue.

[image]

**UPDATE**

What I'm really trying to do is try and apply perspective to some type on top of the 'box' as illustrated below : rather than on the orange or blue areas, on the green part of the grid.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can add type to a perspective grid.

First you need the perspective grid visible before anything can be attached to it.

I'm not sure why but it seems the perspective menu is always greyed out for type, you can either convert to outlines first or attach it to the perspective grid with the **Perspective Selection Tool** (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) – *Note that this will convert the type to outlines anyway*.

[image]

To attach any object to a different plane on the perspective grid you can use the **Plane Switching Widget** that appears when you have a perspective grid visible.

From Adobe help pages:

> when you select the Perspective Grid, a Plane Switching Widget also appears. You can use this widget to select the active grid plane. In Perspective Grid, an active plane is the plane on which you draw an object to project the observer’s view of that portion of the scene.

[image]

You can find out more about perspective grids from the Adobe help pages:

- [Defining Perspective Grids - Video Tutorial](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/atv/cs5-tutorials/defining-perspective-grids.html)
- [Illustrator Help - Define Perspective Grids - Video Tutorial](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/perspective-grid.html)

Comment: It would be nice to have a more accurate timestamp on these answers. Like it is, both of the questions are shown to be added **two hours ago** .

Comment: @CAI. Thanks. If I wanted to put the type on top of that box is that possible? Do I need to do that with three- or one-point perspective?

Comment: Also how would I attach it to the orange 'face' of the cube or even wrap it around both the orange and the blue faces?

Comment: I'll update my answer in a minute

Comment: If you want to wrap anything around multiple planes, check out [this answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/67530/52050) I posted.

Answer (score 2):

You must create perspective grid

[image: example]

Comment: @CAI it's very well possible that the both of you worked on an answer and posted almost simultaneously.

Comment: It's possible with my easy scenario: open question, go to illustrator, go to another task, return to illustrator, record and post answer.

Comment: @sergeydyadyul Thanks. I've added a second image to my question. Is it possible to add the text to the top of the 'box' in that perspective grid?

Comment: @sergeydyadyul Yes its possible happens to me all the time